# Extending rational map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $U$ be a smooth variety of dimension at most $2$ over a field $k$ and $\bar{U}$ be a smooth proper compactification of $U$. Suppose $f: U \to X$ is a morphism of $k$-schemes where  $X$ is a smooth proper $k$-scheme. Then $f$ can be extended to a morphism from $\bar{U}$ to X. 
I know this is true for curve. I can't find any proof in case of surface. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for surfaces. Just imagine that $X$ is the blowup of $\bar{U}$ at a point on the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for surfaces. Consider the projection $\mathbb P^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb P^1$ given by $(x:y:z) \mapsto (x:y)$ which is regular on $U = \mathbb P^2 \setminus \left\{(0:0:1)\right\}$. This map does not extend to all of $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: Upto what extent this is true in case of surfaces..for e.g. does there is a smooth proper compactification $\bar{U}$ of $U$ such that $f$ can be extended to $\bar{U}$?

Comment: 1. There is always a smooth proper compactification $U'$ of $U$ such that $U\to X$ extends to a morphism $U'\to X$. 2. If $X$ has no rational curves, then any rational map $U$ ---> $X$ with $U$ a smooth variety extends to a morphism $U\to X$.